# Accessing values from items in a list

Tags: netlogo

I'm working on a land-use model where each tick represents 3 'real-life' months. I want to calculate the deforestation rate for a whole year and make this information available to certain agents. I define deforestation is defined as the natural log of last year's forest extent divided by this year's forest extent times 100. Currently, I'm calculating deforestation on a quarterly basis like so:

```
to go
   set forest-extent-last-tick count patches with [land-cover = "forest"] 
   ;agents carrying out all their actions, including deforestation
   set forest-extent count patches with [land-cover = "forest"]
end
```

Then I use forest-extent and forest-extent-last-tick to calculate the deforestation rate for that tick. In order to calculate annual deforestation rates, I think I need the forest-extent of the four ticks making up the current year and those of the four ticks making up the previous year.

I'm thinking that the solution could involve a list into which I input the latest forest-extent each tick using the fput command. This way items 0 - 3 of the list would represent the current year, and items 4 - 7 would represent the previous year. **My question is, is there I way I can pull these items from the list into another command/calculation?** I'm thinking something like this :

```
Set deforestation-rate ((sum deforestation-list item 4 item 5 item 6 item 7) / (sum deforestation-list item 0 item 1 item 2 item 3))
```

Also, if there is a different approach to achieving the same results that would totally work for me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the right idea.  `item` has a different syntax, but in any event I think that `sublist` is what you want.

```
Set deforestation-rate ((sum sublist deforestation-list 4 8) / (sum sublist deforestation-list 0 4))
```

`sublist` takes as arguments the list, the beginning item (inclusive) and the ending item (exclusive), so `sublist mylist 4 8` takes items 4, 5, 6 and 7,  and puts them into a list that you can then sum over.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!